# Random name without repeating it self

Tags: php, random

Please tell me, what is my mistake here:

```
$myarrayofnames = ["Tisha","Vesta","Josphine"];
$randompick = array_rand($myarrayofnames,1);
if($myarrayofnames[$randompick] === "Tisha") {
  $myarrayofnames = ["Vesta","Josphine"];
  return $myarrayofnames[$randompick];
}
elseif($myarrayofnames[$randompick] === "Vesta") {
  $myarrayofnames = ["Tisha","Josphine"];
  return $mymyarrayofnames[$randompick];
}
elseif($myarrayofnames[$randompick] === "Josphine") {
  $myarrayofnames = ["Tisha","Vesta"];
  return $mymyarrayofnames[$randompick];
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to pick a random name and make sure the next random name won't be the same as it is now.

Comment: `shuffle` the array, then just `array_shift` elements off it one by one

Comment: you return `$mymyarrayofnames[$randompick];` shouldnt it be `$myarrayofnames[$randompick];` ? This might be a simple fix.

Comment: You mean return $myarrayofnames[$randompick]; right?

Comment: I am sorry, it was just a mistake in the copy-past. The problem is in the logic of the script. @iainn I understand how to shuffle, but don't understand how will it work for me... can you give example please?

Comment: you can just give an array, do array rand on it and unset the value after...

Comment: But to not repeat you will only get 3 names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i asume, you have this code in some function or so. when you get out of the function and call it again for another name, you begin with same array as before, because you **did not 'save'** the modified array anywhere;

as it been suggested in comments, you could use shuffle and shift:

```
class gimmeName{

public $array = array('Tisha', 'Vesta', 'Josephine');

public function giveMeUniqueName(){
    shuffle($this->array);
    return array_shift($this->array);
}
}
```

working demo here: [demo](https://3v4l.org/GWWmL)

Comment: thank you very much! But please tell me if I'm understanding this correctly: there is probability that the same name will be twice once in a while, right? Because of the shuffle... or I don't understand it correctly

Comment: hi, there is not this chance, because array_shift removes first element of array and returns it. this returned element is no longer present in array